# Suppose $f: V\to W$ is an $FG$ homomorphism. Show that $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is a submodule of $V$.

Tags: representation-theory

I think I have done this I just want to check that this is enough to show that it is true, given it is worth 12 marks.

First we recall from Linear Algebra that $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is a subgroup of $V$.
Suppose that $f:V\to W$ is a transformation. Then $f(0_v)=0_w$.

We can prove this.
$f(0_v)=f(0_v+1.0_v)=f(0_v)+1f(0_v)=f(0_v)+f(0_v)$ hence $f(0_v)=0_w$

We have that $f(0)=0$ such that $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is not equal to the empty set.

Now let us suppose that $u,v \in \operatorname{ker}(f)$, with $\lambda \in F$.
$f(u+\lambda v)=f(u)=\lambda f(v)=0+\lambda 0=0$ so that $u+\lambda v$ is in $\operatorname{ker}(f)$.
Hence we have proved that $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is a subgroup.

Now we show that $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is a submodule.

We have that $0$ exists in $V$ such that $f(0)=0$ which implies that $0$ exists in $\operatorname{ker}(f)$. Now assume that $x,y \in \operatorname{ker}(f)$. Then $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)=0+0=0$, hence $x+y \in \operatorname{ker}(f)$.

For all $g \in G$, $f(gx)=gf(x)=g.0=0$ which implies that $gx$ exists in the kernel for all $g \in G$ and $x \in \operatorname{ker}(f)$.

Hence $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is a subgroup of $V$ which is closed under multiplication by elements in $G$, thus it is a submodule of $V$.

any corrections are really welcomed it's probably entirely wrong!

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine to me (except what I've edited that you jumped between using ker and her).

Just some comments:

1. It is not always so clear what you prove at a certain point. It might help with more complicated proofs later on to say what part you are about to prove. This could also be improved already by improved formatting.
2. You should probably use "subspace" instead of "subgroup".
3. You are proving some things several times. For example, you first prove that $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is a subspace of $V$. This already means that it is not empty. You then prove that again as a first step when you are proving it is a submodule. After you prove it is a subspace, you in fact only have to prove it is stable under multiplication with elements of $g$. You don't have to recall the whole argument for subspace. As you remark afterwards in a sentence.